# is it possible to create a multi-frame time series graph in Grafana using multiple metrics from Prometheus datasource?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I want to create a graph which shows the start and end time of an activity which repeats at different times of a day. The start and end times are captured as two separate metrics in the CloudWatch. Graphana will be using Prometheus data source to fetch these metrics.

From my analysis it is observed that we can use Multi-frame time series graph to plot start and end times as dots with different colour. So the Prometheus query should return values for two metrics (start and end times). However I could not figure out the way retrieve two metrics with Prometheus as datasource.

This is the first time I am working with Grafana and Prometheus. I have managed to set up Grafana and Prometheus and implement some monitoring requirements but currently stuck with this. Request to you help.

Comment: To retrieve two metrics you can either use two queries (like [here](https://play.grafana.org/d/000000029/prometheus-demo-dashboard?orgId=1&refresh=5m&editPanel=4)), or use query like `{__name__=~"my_metric_1|my_metric_2"}` (demo [here](https://prometheus.demo.do.prometheus.io/graph?g0.expr=%7B__name__%3D~%22up%7Cnode_cpu_seconds_total%22%7D&g0.tab=1&g0.stacked=0&g0.range_input=1h))